# Prewhiten in R gives "all times contain an NA", but there are no NA values in the time series

Tags: r, time-series

I am using function `prewhiten` from "TSA" package in R. I get an error about `NA` values, but I don't understand it, because I don't have `NA` values in my data. Here is the error message:

```
whitedata <- prewhiten(xhr, ypred, mod1)

Error in na.omit.ts(as.ts(x)) : all times contain an NA
```

It works fine for some data files, but not for others. When I print `xhr` and `ypred` I don't see any `NA` values.

Both are time series:

```
xhr <- ts(data$hr_z,start=1,frequency=10) #convert to a time series
```

ypred <- ts(data$pred_z,start=1,frequency=10) #convert to a time series

Strangely, if I run it with a different model (one built on `ypred`), it runs just fine. The model I am using is:

```
ARIMA(2,1,2)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1     ma2
      1.4835  -0.7641  -0.9574  0.4021
s.e.  0.1136   0.0826   0.1365  0.0910

sigma^2 estimated as 0.02589:  log likelihood=79.98
AIC=-149.96   AICc=-149.65   BIC=-133.55
```

So it appears that something is being done with the data before it goes to the prewhitening and there the NA values arise.

Is there any way/function that let's me check what happens more in detail or let me do the prewhitening manually?

Comment: Post output of  `dput(head(data))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what's wrong in the prewhiten function, but you can do it manually with:

```
 fitwhite <- fitted(Arima(xhr, model=mod1))
 fitwhite2 <- fitted(Arima(ypred, model=mod1))
 print(ccf(fitwhite, fitwhite2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have tried your method, but it works when

```
library(forecast)
x <- xhr - fitted(Arima(xhr, model = mod1))
y <- ypred - fitted(Arima(ypred, model = mod1))
ccf(x, y)
```

You can also do:

```
y <- residuals(Arima(y, model = mod_1))
```

You can check whether the pre-whitening method works by

```
sum(x - mod1$residuals) < 10^6
```

Same answer in [How to prewhiten univariate time series?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/404122/231405).